# Windows 7 BSOD on hibernate

Tags: windows, bsod, minidumps

Sometimes I experience a BSOD when my laptop goes to hibernate. It happens all the way on the end of the hibernation cycle, so the laptop is actually off, harddisk spins down, lights and screen are out, but then after a few seconds I get a BSOD.

Trouble is that it does not happen all the time, maybe 1 out of 5 times, but I cannot find the reason why.

The event log does not give me any real information, just this error:

> The computer has rebooted from a bugcheck. The bugcheck was: 0x0000009f (0x00000003, 0x866f7030, 0x83172ae0, 0x8aaa6658). A dump was saved in: C:\Windows\MEMORY.DMP. Report Id: 020510-29203-01.

I get this error:

```
Problem signature: 
Problem Event Name: BlueScreen 
OS Version: 6.1.7600.2.0.0.256.48 
Locale ID: 1043 
Additional information about the problem: 
BCCode: 9f BCP1: 00000003 BCP2: 866FAB60 BCP3: 83127AE0 BCP4: 8AAFF098
OS Version: 6_1_7600
Service Pack: 0_0
Product: 256_1
Files that help describe the problem:
C:\Windows\Minidump\020710-21902-01.dmp
C:\Users\Rogier\AppData\Local\Temp\WER-45084-0.sysdata.xml
```

Here are 2 dumpfiles, one from last night and 1 from the night before.

- http://www.xs4all.nl/~cpvers/020810-32370-01.rar
- http://www.xs4all.nl/~cpvers/020910-30108-01.rar

I have tried to check out these dmp files, but I am not certain what I should look for.

If somebody can tell me what I should look for in these dump files, so I can go forward with this :)

I have all the latest official drivers for 7 and no strange drivers, so that should not be the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some general advice:

1. Make sure nothing else is connected to the laptop at all, no USB, no VGA, no nothing. Just making sure...
2. See if your laptop has the latest BIOS, and if it does not, flash it to the latest BIOS version.

As far as troubleshooting minidumps, the official Microsoft reference seems to be:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315271

debugging tools must be downloaded from:

http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/DevTools/Debugging/default.mspx

I also found a reference to [WhoCrashed](http://www.resplendence.com/downloads) which, given the minidump as input, will supposedly tell you which driver is most likely responsible for it. I have not used this myself but it looks reputable. Might be easier..

Comment: Good find Jeff regarding WhoCrashed.
 
@Rogier21 According to WhoCrashed the culprit is ntoskrnl.exe which is Windows. Have you checked for BIOS updates for your Laptop? What is the make and type of Laptop?

Comment: Strange, it is a ASUS M50VN laptop, I updated it to the latest BIOS a few weeks ago, will check it now again, but the problem it is happends sometimes... When I press the button it goes OK for 9/10 times, but once or twice it's BSOD.

Strange fact:
When I do it through the day it's ok, when I do it around 1-2AM, it's a fail.

Answer (score 0):

That is exactly what happens to me.  When I try to come out of hibernation, it will bluescreen.  It so far has happened only when I have let it hibernate into the next day.